# Questions displaying username and password information, out of bounds?

Tags: discussion, questions, flags

It is my understanding that if a question contains username and password information to access a certain site, that it violates several of the basic principles of a proper question. While I am usually hesitant to flag a question, I did it this time.

Still I wonder if this is allowed behavior. In this case, after kind requests, the asker did not improve the question.

Even though the help-pages have no mention of policy on displaying passwords, my educated guess is: this is seriously bad (or silly?) behavior and the question should be expunged, not just deleted, to prevent the history to show the password.

> [This is the question I referred to here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756945/search-the-element-present-in-the-left-navigation-bar).

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, thanks, I didn't see that when querying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you come across a post that's got what appears to be valid credentials in it then flag it for moderator attention. If you want you can edit them out, but that's not strictly necessary.

We'll edit them out (if you've not done it already) and then delete the post pending an employee expunging the previous revisions from the database. Once they have been expunged the post can be restored.

What you shouldn't do is draw attention to your edit by posting a comment explaining what you've done. For the most part simply editing the post is enough to remove the credentials from the vast majority of people's view.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I needed to know. I first wanted to do something I have seen done with spam-answers (delete the post, with an edit removing the entire post and a quote saying that the history shows the reason why it was marked as spam and deleted). But in the case of passwords, you wouldn't want to draw attention to it indeed.

Comment: I wouldn't restore this post in particular, there's nothing there to go on and the user has not shown any attempt to make the question more useful.

Comment: @Abel please don't edit spam posts. It makes them harder to remove. Just flag and move on. There are enough people on Stack Overflow to ensure that spam rarely lasts long.

Comment: I never edit spam posts (sorry to have given that impression) for exactly that reason, I just saw that that was the action taken by mods in some cases.

Comment: @Abel - it wouldn't be an action taken by mods. We have better things to do than edit spam posts.